# Map Dictionary of Lists to pd Dataframe Column and Create Repeat Rows Based on n Number of List Contents

Tags: pandas, dataframe, mapping

I am trying to use the following two components 1) a dictionary of lists and 2) a dataframe column composed of the dictionary keys. I would like to to map n number of values to their corresponding key in the existing pandas column, and create duplicate rows based on the number of list contents. I would like to maintain this as a df and not convert to series.

ex. dictionary

```
d = {a:['i','ii'],b:['iii','iv'],c:['v','vi','vii']}
```

ex. dataframe columns

```
    Column1  Column2
0   g        a
1   h        b
2   i        c
```

desired output:

```
    Column1  Column2  Column3
0   g        a        i
1   g        a        ii
2   h        b        iii
3   h        b        iv
4   i        c        v
5   i        c        vi
6   i        c        vii
```

What if another dictionary had to be mapped similarly to these three columns from the output? Say, with the following dictionary:

```
d2 = {'i':['A'],'ii':['B'],'iii':['C','D'],'iv':['E'],'v':['F'];'vi':[G];'vii':['H','I','J']}
```

What if the dictionary was in df format?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592). Please update your question to **show what you have already tried** in a [**minimal reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and then ask a _specific question_ about your algorithm or technique. For further information, see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

use map to create a new column and then explode the list into rows

```
df=df.assign(Column3 = df['Column2'].map( d))
df.explode('Column3')
```

```
    Column1 Column2 Column3
0   g   a   i
0   g   a   ii
1   h   b   iii
1   h   b   iv
2   i   c   v
2   i   c   vi
2   i   c   vii
```

follow the same to map to Column 3

```
df=df.assign(Column4 = df['Column3'].map( d2))
df=df.explode('Column4')
df
```

```
    Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
0   g   a   i   A
0   g   a   ii  B
1   h   b   iii C
1   h   b   iii D
1   h   b   iv  E
2   i   c   v   F
2   i   c   vi  G
2   i   c   vii H
2   i   c   vii I
2   i   c   vii J
```